# Use mulitple usernames?

Tags: database, permissions, username

Can I configure wordpress to use two database usernames, one to read (which has read-only permissions in the database) and one to post (who is hidden in a protected wp-admin directory) for security purposes?

The point is that even if someone hacks wordpress, they won't have permission to do any harm.

Comment: Define "hacks WordPress". What situation would this protect against?

Comment: @Milo like an sql injection attack

Comment: core inserts all use prepared statements. it's probably simpler to vet any plugins for unsafe queries.

Comment: @Milo what about select?

Comment: any query that accepts input in core should be prepared.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress does not allow this "configuration".  And I seriously doubt you would have any luck writing a plugin that would take care of this in a complete way.  The WPDB class is heavily utilized throughout the site, and sifting through read-only vs write-enabled uses would be daunting.